# WordPress include custom field in search

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type of `post_type_1` in WordPress, I also have a custom field  in that post type of `custom_field_data`

I am doing a search for `apples` by querying posts using `wp_query` like this...

```
$search_term = 'apples';

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => array('post_type_1'),
    'post_status'    => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's'              => sanitize_text_field( $search_term)
);

$results= new WP_Query( $args );
```

This works correctly and returns all posts with `apples` in the title, but I would also like to extend the search to the custom field `custom_field_data` so the query will return all posts with `apples` in either title or custom field.

What is my best approach? I have tried using a meta_query but haven't been successful. Does anybody have an example?

Comment: If you use `meta_query` you will only get posts where custom field value is `apples` which will exclude the results that have `apples` in title but don't have the matching custom field value. You can achieve this by running two queries one for search and another for custom field and push results in array and print only unique results. Not the best solution but gets you working right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will work for `custom field search`.

```
$custom_field = $_GET['custom_field '] != '' ? $_GET['custom_field '] : '';
$search_term = 'apples';

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => array('post_type_1'),
    'post_status'    => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's'              => sanitize_text_field( $search_term),
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
                          array(
                                'key'     => 'custom_field_key', 
                                'value'   => $custom_field ,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                                ),
                            )
    );
$results= new WP_Query( $args );
```

Tested and works well.